# Snake game in C language

Tags: c

I want to make a snake game without using graphics. The problem is that the snake will have to change direction when pressing the corresponding button. How do I make my program respond to my button without needing to scan a character. Because, if I add an instruction such as scanf() or getch(), my snake would stop moving and that's not how a snake game works.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation is dependent on the system you want to use. Windows has other functions to check for keypresses than Linux. For Windows you can use Console.KeyAvailable. For Linux you can best look at a console library like ncurses.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example if you can?

Comment: For Windows you can use Console.KeyAvailable.

Comment: For Linux you can best look at a console library like ncurses.

Comment: Edited the answer to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

On every system it is possible to have `getchar()`(or similar functions) non-blocking. On Unix system, the solution is to set the terminal (`tty`) in raw mode. To simplify your life, you can also use some library to do it for you, a lib like `curses` or one of its variants. Such a lib will also help you to *draw* chars on screen exactly as you may dream for an ASCII snake program.

There is also different solutions on Windows system.

You can also use multi-threading. One thread blocking on terminal I/Os and transmitting read chars to the other moving the snake.